# How to find which features are responsible for predicted label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I am working on a machine learning project and wants to know by using the sklearn how we can find the best feature responsible for predicted label in python.

Let suppose we fit the model and the wants to predict
`model.predict([1,2,3])-> let suppose it says you passed the test.` but what the weightage of the features for predicting only for this prediction
`model.predict([1,2,3])`

Suppose a dataset with 5 columns. Let's call them: id, X_1, X_2, X_3, result. X_1,X_2,X_3 have the numerical values 1-5.

I need to show that this result was caused by X_1,X_2 with weightage of 0.8900% and 0.3900% or any graph which through i can use fully understand. How can I show that X_1 and X_2 has more influence on result than X_3? only for this prediction `model.predict([1,2,3])`

I need a simple answer or any code which can helps me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it really depends on your data, model and what you want to achiev. That being said the easiest approach would be to make different experiments and compare the results. So make a model with X_1,X_2 and X_3 and then a model with X_1 and X_2.

More complex solutions could be to use feature selection. [Here a short introduction.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/)
For example you could use the `feature importance` to get insight how much each feature contributes to the prediction. [An easy example with code can be found here.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-feature-importance-with-python/)

```
**Example with a random forest model:**
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot

# define dataset
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=3, n_informative=2, random_state=42)
# define the model
model = RandomForestRegressor()
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y)
# get importance
importance = model.feature_importances_
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: X_ %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i+1,v))
```

In the output we can see that X_3 contributes more to the prediction then X_1 so it might be an idea(atleaset if we suspected that from the beginning) to make another model with only X_1 and X_2. We can also think about excluding X_1 because it does not contribute that much to the prediction if we are worried about the dimensionality of our data.:

[image]

Keep in mind that this is not the only approach but one of many. It really depends on what data you have which models you are using and what you are trying to do.

**EDIT:**
As you asked now about prediction. You can use [LIME](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-model-predictions-with-lime-a582fdff3a3b) the shed some light into how different features influence your predictions. As i don't know your code I can't really provide correct code for your case. For implementation you can look [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/prashant111/explain-your-model-predictions-with-lime/notebook) or simply by googeling.
An example Code can look like this:

```
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular
 # LIME has one explainer for all the models
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X, verbose=True, mode='regression')

# Choose the 5th instance and use it to predict the results
j = 5
exp = explainer.explain_instance(X[j], model.predict, num_features=3)
# Show the predictions
exp.show_in_notebook(show_table=True)
```

The output would look soemthing like this:
[image]
[image]

So here an interpretation could be, that feature 0 and feature 2 contributed the strongest to the prediction and also that feature 2 might be pointing into a more negativ prediciton direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and it gives me alot of information. But let suppose if i enter only one entry for prediction-> model.prediction([4,2,3]) 
and wants to know which feature did more help to predict it's result. How we can do that?
I really appreciate if you answer this question too.

Comment: Mhh you could try to use LIME. Will write up an update on that. But be careful with tuning your model on test data might lead to not ideal performance in a real life scenario!

Comment: Thanks alot. Can i share my code and files with you ? Is there any possible way to contact you email or contact detail?

Comment: You can use a google colab or github to upload your files and I can take a look at them.